# $R(A) = C(A)$ for non-invertible matrix implies diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a square non-invertible matrix such that $Rows(A) = Cols(A)$ (They span the same vector space).
>
> **Prove or disprove** - $A$ is diagonalizable.

I tried very hard to find a disproval example of this matrix $A$ but I always end up with a matrix the fullfil the conditions.

It feels a little bit that I might prove that such matrix $A$ is symmetric, and therefore depending on the spectral theorem it is also diagonalizable.

**Any hints ? Thank you !**

Comment: What is denoted by Rows(A) and Cols(A)?

Comment: Rows(A) and Cols(A) span the same vector space.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Oh! I see. I thought of the dimensions which are the same, not the subspaces. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.  For instance, the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}
$$
has the same row and column spaces, but fails to be diagonalizable.